# Which is the RAID level meeting the following criteria?

Tags: raid

We have 3 HDDs, same capacity (2TB). Which RAID level allows me to use 4TB of space and in case any of the 3 HDDs fails (but only one) I have all the 4TB untouched and safe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is RAID 5, but it's *really* not difficult for you to have looked this up yourself, is it?